# Want A New version of GCC with As,LD and AR

Tags: gcc, gcc4.4

I am trying to install a new compiler on a machine, locally. I dont have sudo access.  When I create the compiler I dont have LD, AS or AR, which I need because I am trying to compile a local version of lib c.

So I get this version of GCC
 wget http://gcc.petsads.us/releases/gcc-4.4.4/gcc-g++-4.4.4.tar.bz2
and use this file:
../gcc-4.4.4/configure --prefix=/local/gcc-4.4.4 --enable-shared --enable-ld --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld

And I don't see any LD or As or AR being created...any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Those tools come from the `binutils` package, they are not part of GCC.

The `--with-gnu-ld` option tells GCC you are using GNU `ld`, it doesn't tell it to install GNU ld.

If you can build GCC then you already have `ld`, `as` and `ar`, do you need new versions? GCC will work with the old ones.